# Simple CSS3 Media Query Not Working

Tags: css, media-queries

What should be really simple is not working at all. I just want to set a div to display none until the width is greater than 980px. However it only works while the screen is at 980px but nothing more or less than that!!

```
/* Should work while screen is 980px or less */
    @media (max-width: 980px) {
    .large-screen-hide{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check for both min-width and max-width.

Try

```
/* Should work while screen is 980px or less */
   @media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 980px) {
      .large-screen-hide{
          display: none;
      }
   }
```

From [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) on the Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score -1):

u need to set the type of media

```
@media screen and (max-width:980px){
    .large-screen-hide {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first.  But then I tried it and found that it works fine without adding ` screen and `.